# How to run two fragments each with their own AsyncTasks

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask, swiperefreshlayout

I have a layout with 2 tabs in it which are implemented via fragments i.e. each tab has its own fragment. They is a SwipeRefreshLayout in each of the layouts associated with the fragments.
Also there are two async tasks which make an http call to a script that returns JSON data.
I implemented the first async task and it worked fine but however when I tried executing the second one the app keeps crashing. Log cat is not of much help but these were the most important lines I saw:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

These errors occured when an http request was created. Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: show code there is some problem in AsyncTasks

Comment: Where do you call the second AsyncTask?

Comment: call Looper.getMainLooper()
  just above  your handler= new Handler()

Comment: Show the code of the fragment that's crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a different thread from the UI thread you must create a Handle and send a runnable for the UI thread . follows the code

```
Handler handler = new Handler (Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post (new Runnable () {
     @Override
     public void run () {
         // ... Update view
     }
});
```

Comment: created a new method and put the handler in it. called from the swiperefresh and it works just fine.